What is the idiomatic way to create a U to V mapper function template in C++?
I am learning about C++ right now, and trying out some of the templating features. I am trying to create a generic template that receives a function F from U to V, a std::array of type U,  and then returns (via NRVO) an array of type V.
This is what I came up with on a first pass. It seems reasonable to my untrained eye, but the compiler doesn't like it:
template <typename F, typename U, typename V, std::size_t N> std::array<V, N> map(F mapper, const std::array<U, N> &elements)
{
  std::array<V, N> newArray{};
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    newArray[i] = mapper(elements[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

// ...

int main()
{
  std::array<int, 10> ints1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  auto doubles1 = map([](int x) -> double { return x*2.5; }, ints1);
}

I am using clang 16.0.6, and it tells me:
functional.cpp:87:19: error: no matching function for call to 'map'
  auto doubles1 = map([](int x) -> double { return x*2.5; }, ints1);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
functional.cpp:22:79: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'V'
template <typename F, typename U, typename V, std::size_t N> std::array<V, N> map(F mapper, std::array<U, N> &elements)
                                                                              ^
1 error generated.

To my mind, it seems like there should be something I can do to hint to the compiler that the lambda returns a double, and hence the auto should be deduced as std::array<double, N>. Is there something easy I am missing? Thank you.
I expected the code to compile of course, but something is not quite right. I am still pretty new to C++ lingo, so I am having trouble knowing what exactly to google to resolve this. One possible solution I came up with was to use an out-parameter:
template <typename F, typename U, typename V, std::size_t N> void map_outParam(F mapper, std::array<U, N> &elements, std::array<V, N> &out)
{
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    out[i] = mapper(elements[i]);
  }
}

This compiles just fine, and works as expected. However, it's not as clean as I would like.

If you want to allow other mapping functions, you should be able to use auto as the result parameter, and determine the return type of your mapper via std::invoke_result. Let me see if I can get that to work...

I'd be curious to see what you're talking about with the std::invoke_result. Based on the other answer, I need to do some reading on template type deduction. In my code, U is int and V is double. But this was just for example. I was trying to understand the general case for any U/V combination.

Basically, you can just use the result type of your callback function to figure out the type for the result array.
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

template <typename F, typename U, std::size_t N> auto map(F mapper, std::array<U, N> &elements)
{
  std::array<std::invoke_result_t<F, U>, N> newArray{};
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    newArray[i] = mapper(elements[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

// ...

int main()
{
  std::array<int, 10> ints1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  auto doubles1 = map([](int x) -> double { return x*2.5; }, ints1);
}


This is also really cool. I'll have to read about this std::invoke_result_t. It seems to remove the need to explicitly specify the mapper return type. Thanks!

Note also that your loop is doing the same thing as std::transform. This answer already beat me to it on the type-traits solution, but here's my implementation anyway. The explicit return type on the lambda is not required. https://godbolt.org/z/EexfPE79j

Let the C++ code golf contest commence! :)

Yeah, I was just doing a "minimal change" to the existing code, instead of rewriting it.

You were close but the ordering of the template arguments were confusing:
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename V, std::size_t N, typename F, typename U>
std::array<V, N> map(
    F mapper,
    std::array<U, N>& elements
) {
  std::array<V, N> newArray{};
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    newArray[i] = mapper(elements[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

// ...

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> ints1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    auto doubles1 = map<double>(
        [](int x) -> double {
            return x*2.5; 
        },
        ints1
    );

    for (auto it = doubles1.begin(); it != doubles1.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout<<*it<<'\n';
    }
}

The difference is that there's a notion of implicit template arguments, where the compiler deduce the template types. The way you ordered them originally didn't respect that V can't be deduced, hence no matching function.
So the sample above adjusts the ordering and explicitly defines what V is.

Brilliant! I knew there had to be a straightforward way to do this. I'll need to do a little more reading about template type deduction. Thanks :)

Mapped elements may not be default-constructible.
You can do this more easily with the help of std::apply and the std::array's CTAD
template <typename F, typename U, std::size_t N> 
auto map(F mapper, std::array<U, N>& elements)
{
  return std::apply([&](auto&... args) {
    return std::array{mapper(args)...};
  }, elements);
}

